# Machine crashed while switching branches

Tags: git

I was switching branches when my machine crashed. Essentially Android Studio (Presumably Gradle did some sync thing), Itunes and Chrome had a race to consume as much ram as possible when windows decided it might do a virus scan (I saw the notifications, watched the machine freeze and went to bed). Now, after a restart, any git actions I happen to perform return the following message

```
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

Since I was using the repository to track changes locally I hadn't pushed it up to my server so I can't do the usual "delete and clone trick". I only have this one source for `.git` is there some way to recover the repository ? I suspect there is some kind of file within `.git` has invalidated it or there might be a log file detailing how far the switch went before the machine crashed but I'm not sure how to proceed.

The following details the contents of my repository folder. It seems all the objects/refs are presents (I've redacted these as  I doubt a list of hash keys are relevant).

```
.git
| |-hooks
| | |-applypatch-msg.sample
| | |-commit-msg.sample
| | |-fsmonitor-watchman.sample
| | |-post-checkout
| | |-post-commit
| | |-post-merge
| | |-post-update.sample
| | |-pre-applypatch.sample
| | |-pre-commit.sample
| | |-pre-push
| | |-pre-push.sample
| | |-pre-rebase.sample
| | |-pre-receive.sample
| | |-prepare-commit-msg.sample
| | \-update.sample
| |-info
| | |-exclude
| | \-refs
| |-lfs
| | |-objects
| | | |-0e
| | | | |-8e
| | | | \-0e8e3708b2f1e19c47aba47ea403e9ca79d137327c91d17259b0d237eefe26f1
| | | | ...
| | | |-logs
| | | \-20181114T090724.0218977.log
| | | \-20181114T090724.1247973.log
| | | \-20181114T090724.2626623.log
| | | \-20181114T090724.3925379.log
| | | \-20181114T090724.5124194.log
| | | \-20181114T090724.6482897.log
| | | \-20181114T090724.8071324.log
| | | \-20181114T090724.9429992.log
| | | \-20181114T090725.1018458.log
| | | \-20181114T090725.2317178.log
| | |-tmp
| | | |-objects
| |-logs
| \-HEAD
| | |-refs
| | | |-heads
| | | \-checkout
| | | \-development
| | | \-filter_by_fragment
| | | \-filter_by_model
| | | \-filter_by_repository
| | | \-master
| | | \-navigation
| | | \-structure_by_adjacency_list
| | | \-structure_by_foreign_key
| | | \-structure_by_modified_pre-order_tree_traversal
| |-objects
| | |-0e
| | \-1fc38e5762a43d46fc3fa149c846b851e1fdfc
| | ...
| | |-info
| | \-packs
| | |-pack
| | \-pack-4ef6cd852a2081fb393e4f3720cbd01a151822d4.idx
| | \-pack-4ef6cd852a2081fb393e4f3720cbd01a151822d4.pack
| |-refs
| | |-heads
| | \-checkout
| | \-development
| | \-filter_by_fragment
| | \-filter_by_model
| | \-filter_by_repository
| | \-master
| | \-navigation
| | \-structure_by_adjacency_list
| | \-structure_by_foreign_key
| | \-structure_by_modified_pre-order_tree_traversal
| | |-tags
COMMIT_EDITMSG
HEAD
ORIG_HEAD
config
description
index
packed-refs
tortoisegit.data
tortoisegit.index
```

While probably irrelevant I had installed git LFS into the respository and mostly work with it through tortoisegit.

The contents of `.git/HEAD` was blank (Asked for by Mr./Ms. Torek). Adjusting this to reflect the original branch I was on before switching returns the following error:

```
error: bad signature
fatal: index file corrupt
```

Comment: What is your directory structure? Do you see the `.git` folder that should hold the repo data?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I included the structure I have under my `.git` folder. It seems to be in tact so the question is why might git think I do not have a `.git` folder

Comment: Inspect the *contents* of `.git/HEAD`. Whatever branch you were on at the time, the file should read `ref: refs/heads/<branch>`. If it doesn't, create it with those contents and see if Git is happy again. (Note: there is a single space after the colon in `ref:`, and the line ends with newline rather than CRLF, though perhaps CRLF works on Windows.)

Comment: @torek thanks, it got me a new error to investigate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, the first part was a bad `HEAD` file, which is not very surprising as the `HEAD` file is the most active.  Writing a good `HEAD` got you the subsequent complaint about a bad index file.

The index contains information about all the files that are going to be put into the *next* commit.  Initially, this is just a copy of all the files that are in the *current* commit.  When you run `git add file`, that puts the new version of the file (the new content) into the index.<sup>1</sup>  If the file itself is all-new, the file goes into the index for the first time.<sup>2</sup>

The index is therefore usually the *second*-most active file in the repository.  But, lucky for you, unless you `git add`ed some content, and then overwrote that content in the work-tree with *other* content, or removed the work-tree copy, you still have a copy of that data in the work-tree.  (Files that you left unchanged since Git extracted the commit *into* your work-tree have a good copy in *two* other places, namely, the current commit and the work-tree.)

What this means is that in most cases you can simply *remove* the index, then have Git rebuild one from the current commit:

```
rm .git/index
git reset       # the default, equivalent to `git reset --mixed HEAD`
```

The `git reset` creates an all-new index to replace the one just removed.  The new index holds the same files as the current commit, i.e., all your `git add` work is un-done.<sup>3</sup>  But as long as the copies in the work-tree are still OK, you can just `git add` them again to copy them back into the *new* index.

---

<sup>1</sup>Technically, the contents themselves go into the repository as a loose object, and the index just gets the new object's hash ID.  The effect, however, is as if the file lives inside the index.

<sup>2</sup>If the file is in some other commit, but not in the current commit, it's may not be exactly the *first* time, but what happens is that the index acquires a new entry, rather than overwriting some existing entry, so that too is close enough.

<sup>3</sup>If you set the assume-unchanged or skip-worktree bits on any entries in the old index, those are gone as well, but you can just set them again on the new index.

Comment: Thanks, I hoped it might be as easy as removing/tweaking a file or two. As I understand it a commit is really a hash in the index mapping a set of hashes that represent the changes in ones repository (Your loose objects in footnote 1). Given that I was switching branches when it all went skew I didn't find any "un-added" files (As per footnote 2) only un-committed changes. Should I expect any complications down the line at all ? like a missing hash or something ? I presume `git reset` handles all the quirks but I'll run `git fsck` too.

Comment: The `git fsck` is a good idea: it will make sure the contents of all objects make sense and match their hash IDs. As for what a commit "really is", you're right that there is a hash ID, but that's the ID of a Git object that contains the metadata *about* the commit (your name, email, log message, etc) plus the parent hash IDs plus a tree-object hash ID. The tree object maps from file names to blob hash IDs (and possible sub-trees), and the blob hash IDs give the file's contents. All of these are *snapshots* with the full content as-is. Any object may be either loose or "packed", with [cont'd]

Comment: ... with the difference being completely invisible to normal Git usage, but amounting to how much compression the object gets. A pack file contains many objects, which can be delta-compressed against other objects in the same pack file. Pack files are the *only* place that Git stores things as changes: by the time you (or Git) retrieve an object by hash ID, it's a stand-alone entity.